# Laravel error Route [digiflazz.mainsettings.showform] not defined. (View: D:\2024\project\resources\views\admin\layouts\sidebar.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I tried to edit the route and I think it is correct but when I run it the result is an error
`Route [digiflazz.mainsettings.showform] not defined. (View: D:\2024\project\resources\views\admin\layouts\sidebar.blade.php)`

route/web.php

```
        /* ===== Digiflazz Main Settings ===== */
        Route::get('digiflazz-main-settings', 'Admin\Digiflazz\mainsettingsController@showGenerateProductForm')->name('digiflazz.mainsettings.showform');
        Route::post('digiflazz-main-settings-fetch', 'Admin\Digiflazz\mainsettingsController@fetchFromDigiflazz')->name('digiflazz.mainsettings.fetch');
        Route::post('digiflazz-main-settings-update', 'Admin\Digiflazz\mainsettingsController@updateproduct')->name('digiflazz.mainsettings.update');
```

app\Http\Controllers\Admin\Digiflazz\mainsettingsController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Digiflazz;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use App\Models\DigiflazzMain; // Ensure this model exists and matches your database structure

class mainsettingsController extends Controller
{
    // Method to show the form
    public function showGenerateProductForm()
    {
        return view('admin.digiflazz.mainsettings.generateproduct');
    }

    // Method to fetch data from Digiflazz API
    public function fetchFromDigiflazz(Request $request)
    {
        // Define the API endpoint and your credentials
        $apiUrl = 'https://api.digiflazz.com/v1/price-list';
        $username = 'your_username'; // Replace with your username
        $apiKey = 'your_api_key'; // Replace with your API key
        $sign = md5($username.$apiKey.'pricelist'); // Adjust according to Digiflazz's documentation

        // Make a request to the Digiflazz API
        $response = Http::post($apiUrl, [
            'cmd' => 'prepaid',
            'username' => $username,
            'sign' => $sign,
        ]);

        // Check if the response is successful
        if ($response->successful()) {
            $data = $response->json();

            // Iterate through the data and store each item in the database
            foreach ($data['data'] as $item) {
                DigiflazzMain::create([
                    'product_name' => $item['product_name'],
                    // Continue mapping other fields...
                ]);
            }

            return back()->with('success', 'Data fetched and stored successfully.');
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', 'Failed to fetch data from Digiflazz.');
        }
    }

    // Method to handle manual updates
    public function manualUpdate(Request $request)
    {
        // Implement logic for manual updates
    }

    // Method to delete a category
    public function deleteCategory(Request $request)
    {
        // Implement logic for category deletion
    }
}
```

resources\views\admin\digiflazz\mainsettings.generateproduct.blade.php

```
{{-- resources\views\admin\digiflazz\mainsettings.generateproduct.blade.php --}}
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>Manage Digiflazz Products</h1>
    <form action="{{ route('digiflazz.mainsettings.fetch') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" {{ $isDatabaseEmpty ? '' : 'disabled' }}>Ambil Semua Data</button>
    </form>
    
    @if (!$isDatabaseEmpty)
        <form action="{{ route('admin.digiflazz.manualUpdate') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Manual Update</button>
        </form>

        <form action="{{ route('digiflazz.mainsettings.fetch') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <select name="category" class="form-control">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category }}">{{ $category }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" {{ $categories->isEmpty() ? 'disabled' : '' }}>Hapus Kategori</button>
        </form>
    @endif
</div>
@endsection
```

resources\views\admin\layouts\sidebar.blade.php

```
<li class="sidebar-item">
    <a class="sidebar-link" href="{{ route('digiflazz.mainsettings.showform') }}">
        <i class="fas fa-code text-orange"></i>
        <span class="hide-menu">@lang('Main Settings')</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

how do I do it so that when I press menu **Main Settings** it will get a view of **mainsettings.generateproduct.blade.php** ??

I've tried changing routes but the problem is always the same, I'm a beginner and I want to learn.
Thank you to those who are willing to answer

Comment: First step: php artisan route:clear

Comment: If after route clear still doesn't work, check if routes are not grouped in with a groupe route name.